# Упаковать числовой массив ( pack() ), для добавления в БД blob

Tags: php, mysql, sql, массивы

Привет, не могу разобраться, как правильно упаковать числовой массив, для последующей записи его в в БД в ячейку blob.
Упаковать нужно при помощи pack()

```
$aOrder = [];
for ($iDay = 0; $iDay<366; ++$iDay) {
    $aOrder[] = $iDay;
}
$result = pack('i*', ...$aOrder);
```

Данный код сработает, через unpack() можно обратно получить массив.

Но нельзя $result добавить в БД в BLOB.
Ошибок сайт не выдаёт, просто не добавляет.

($iDay в значения массива добавил просто для примера, что бы все значения были разные. Если сделать все значения одинаковыми, то каким то чудом, для меня, упакованный массив добавляется в БД)

Я так понял, что в $result записываются запрещённые символы, из-за которых и не идёт запись в БД (начало $result, если его вывести на экран, выглядит так:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Как правильно реализовать упаковку числового массива, для последующего добавления в BLOB при помощи pack()?

сяп =)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74791/discussion-on-question-by-gagablik----pack--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

РЕШЕНИЕ.

blob данные добавил при помощи изменения sql запроса на:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $result);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```